# Find team/s that has the most consecutive wins

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find the team/s that have the most consecutive wins, but I don't know how to approach the question.

This is my dataset:

```
df = {
    "game": ["1201", "1202", "1203", "1204", "1205"],
    "home team": ["B", "C", "D", "E", "D"],
    "away team": ["A", "B", "C ", "D", "A"],
    "winner": ["home", "away", "home ", "away", "away"],
}
```

I am trying to get something like this:
| team | number of wins |
| ---- | -------------- |
|   B  |       2        |
|   D  |       2        |

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df['winner'] = df['winner'] + ' team'

df_winners = df.melt(['game', 'winner']).query('winner == variable')
print(df_winners)
print(df_winners.groupby('value')['game'].count())
```

Output:

```
   game     winner   variable value
0  1201  home team  home team     B
6  1202  away team  away team     B
8  1204  away team  away team     D
9  1205  away team  away team     A


    Value
A    1
B    2
D    1
Name: game, dtype: int64
```

##### Update after correcting input dataframe:

```
df = {
    "game": ["1201", "1202", "1203", "1204", "1205"],
    "home team": ["B", "C", "D", "E", "D"],
    "away team": ["A", "B", "C ", "D", "A"],
    "winner": ["home", "away", "home", "away", "away"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Then run,

```
df['winner'] = df['winner'] + ' team'

df_winners = df.melt(['game', 'winner']).query('winner == variable')
print(df_winners)
print(df_winners.groupby('value')['game'].count())
```

Updated Output:

```
   game     winner   variable value
0  1201  home team  home team     B
2  1203  home team  home team     D
6  1202  away team  away team     B
8  1204  away team  away team     D
9  1205  away team  away team     A


   value
A    1
B    2
D    2
Name: game, dtype: int64
```

Comment: What happened to game 1203?

Comment: @CarlosGDCJ Error in your input data.   There is an extra space after home on 1203.

Comment: Error in the input data? Isn't it better to adjust the code to fit the data instead of the data to fit the code?

Comment: Yes, @CarlosGDCJ you can adjust to code to be more robust, but I figure this was just a type by the OP.

Comment: I understand, my friend. Nice answer btw. I wouldn't have thought of using `melt` and `query` like that.